# Add custom button in profile page of BuddyPress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I tried adding a custom button in BuddyPress profile page using below mentioned code. But when I added that code, only Name & Profile picture was appearing & no other content generated through BuddyPress was appearing:

```
function mapbtn_custom_button() {
    echo '<div class="mapbtn"><a href="#" title="Fashion World">map</a><div>';
}
add_filter( 'bp_before_member_header_meta', 'mapbtn_custom_button' );
```

Comment: improved code formatting

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to hook a filter to an action call.

Try this instead:

```
add_action( 'bp_before_member_header_meta', 'mapbtn_custom_button' );
```

Comment: In both case (using filter or action), only profile name & picture is appearing and nothing else but in source code, all contents are there.

Comment: Are you adding your function in your-theme/functions,php or in plugins/bp-custom.php?  Do you have debug turned on? http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: `[15-Mar-2015 11:26:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  has_cap was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in /home/SITE_DIRECTORY/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3495`
[15-Mar-2015 11:26:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/SITE_DIRECTORY/wp-includes/functions.php:3495) in /home/SITE_DIRECTORY/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/stats.php on line 434`